# multiple fields with yup and react hook forms

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

I'm trying to do this with yup and react-hook-forms

For example, if I'm given an array of ids, then I would like to have a field for each id. The ids are random (i.e., we could have 4 ids or 100 ids). For now, I just want to see if all the input is filled (`.required()`)

This is how I would handle validation without any libraries

```
export default function App(){
  const [ids, setIds] = React.useState(arr1)
  const inputValues = React.useRef({});

  const handleSubmit = () => {
      const { current: values } = inputValues;
      console.log(values);
  };

  const validateInput = event => {
      const { name, value } = event.target;
      // validation done here
      if(true){
          inputValues.current[name] = value;
      }
  };

  return (
      <div>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              {ids.map(num => (
                  <input name={num} onChange={validateInput} required key={num} />
              ))};
              <button type="submit">submit</button>
          </form>
      </div>
  );
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-4jnfx2?file=App.tsx

Now how would I do this with yup and react hook forms to validate the input ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the sandbox below, you can find an implementation with React Hook Form as [shown here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-js-forked-tq4wo0?file=/src/App.js);

As it's pretty easy to follow from it's own [documentation here](https://react-hook-form.com/), you don't need any other variables. So that I made it a bit simplification and only used necessary `handleSubmit` function, instead of `validateInput` and references.

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const [data, setData] = useState("");
  const [ids] = useState(["1", "3", "40", "18"]);

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setData(JSON.stringify(data));
      })}
    >
      {ids.map((num) => (
        <input key={num} name={num} {...register(num, { required: true })} />
      ))}
      <p>{data}</p>
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code. I don't have experience with `TypeScript` so I have wrote it in `JavaScript`

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
import * as yup from 'yup';

const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

const createSchema = (keys, valueSchema) => yup.object().shape(keys.reduce((acc, key) => ({ ...acc, [key]: valueSchema }), {}));

const mySchema = createSchema(arr1, yup.string().required());

const App = () => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(mySchema),
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      {arr1.map((item) => (
        <div key={item} style={{ border: '1px solid black' }}>
          <input {...register(`${item}`)} />
          <p>{errors?.[item]?.message}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
};

export default App;
```